# Calling a method in my derived class in Java

Tags: java, oop, overriding

I wrote this sample with Java.

```
public class Person {
    public static void ShowInfo() {
        System.out.println("I am Person");
    }
}

public class Student extends  Person {
    public static void ShowInfo() {
        System.out.println("I am Student");
    }
}
```

When I run this code:

```
 Person person = new Student();
 person.ShowInfo();
```

Why do I get `I am Person`?

Comment: In the first sample, you're doing `Person person = new Teacher();` and in the second one you're doing `Student person = new Student();`. That's different. Doing `Person person = new Student();` in the Java code would yield the same result.

Comment: @user2336315 I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple. In Java, derived classes are implicitly polymorphic. You need `virtual` and `override` keywords (also when using an `abstract` class or `interface`) in C# to get the same behavior.

Although to get the same C# "behavior" in Java, you can simply tag on the `final` keyword in the method signature:

```
public final void ShowInfo() {
        System.out.println("I am Student");
}
```

And I didn't know  static methods in Java were polymorphic :O Is this your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

For

### Why i get I am person.

I dont know why this answer is unexected for you.

There are two things i want to say:

- By default java methods are virtual. But static methods are not virtual by default and hence this is not a case of dynamic polymorphism. If it were polymorphic you would get "I am Student" instead of "I am Person".
- It is really a bad practice to call static method with obj reference, prefer calling it with ***ClassName***

Answer (score 1):

What you do is not *method overloading* but *method hiding* instead. Static methods can be redefined in the child class (with the same signature) and this is called method hiding. The version of the static method called (the one in the subclass or parent class) depends on the reference type, not the the real instance type at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Lews Therin (a fan of TWoT I see) is right:

Try writing this:

```
public class Teacher : Person
{
    public override void ShowInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am a teacher");
    }
}
```

and see what you get

Comment: This looks more like a comment to @Lews answer than an answer. Maybe you can add more info to make it more of an answer in itself?

Comment: It's true, I started writing it, but then Lews answer popped up, so I added reference to his.

Answer (score 0):

In Java all methods are virtual by default. That's why you get the overridden method (which is default as well) in Java even when the reference is of the base type.